# Face splitting tool

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

[image]

Is there a tool to split this cubes faces or face into 4 **equally spaced** faces?
So it will look like this:

[image]

Maybe just to split it into 2 equally spaced faces that I can apply twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Select the face, then press <kbd>W</kbd> and select 'Subdivide'.
[image]

The result should look like this:
[image]

At the bottom the tools shelf on the right side of the 3D view you can also change the number of cuts and a bunch of other options.
[image]
If the tools shelf is not visible, press <kbd>T</kbd> while you mouse cursor is inside the 3D view to show it.