# How to connect vertices to a plane?

Tags: animation, vertices

I want to ask if that possible to extrude a vertices and connect it in a middle of a plane ?? And If that possible how to do it ?
it's my first question and i hope i can find the answer here :D
Thanks ..
[image]

Comment: Could you show some screenshots of what you want to achieve?

Comment: It is nice you have added a picture but now I am even more confused about what do you want to do. What does A and B mean? What does the selected face mean? And there is the plane you are talking about?

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12252/face-splitting-tool

Comment: i want to extrude a new plane from point A to point B but sometimes i need to make a curve in between so am asking if theres any way to extrude a vertices from any point of a plane or an edge and make more vertices in the way to other point to control your curve .
i hope you get the idea

Comment: This is not extrude but splitting, then there are several tools for that - namely Subdivide (W -> Subdivide), Knife tool (K) and Loop cuts (Ctrl + R). Just fiddle with these on some test scene to see what will work for you.

Comment: knife tool (K) was the best of them ..thanks @JanKadeřábek

Answer (score 3):

You can create a vertex in the middle of the plane poking the plane's face (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).
Then set the snap type to vertex (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> -> Vertex) and extrude vertices (select + <kbd>E</kbd>) to the plane's middle vertex while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> so you have snapping temporarily enabled while dragging.
If it is a single object, its even easier - select each 2 vertices and hit <kbd>F</kbd> to make a connection (instead of extruding).

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.
[image]

**UPDATE** (after the question was modified):

So you didn't want to extrude anything, you just need to split an edge.
Then there are several tools for such task - namely Subdivide (<kbd>W</kbd> -> Subdivide), Knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and Loop cuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Just fiddle with these tools on some testing scene to see what will work for you best.